# How to get an AWS VM to run Wolfram with a GPU (or Azure for that matter)

Tags: neural-networks, amazon-web-services, cloud

I have a neural network application that is too big for my Mac desktop. I've been looking at using RemoteBatchSubmit to Azure as a solution. I've gotten it to work using the base VM provided by Azure. But now I want to do training using a GPU (lots of convolution layers). If I try to run the example in the Wolfram documentation on the base VM, the job will run but I get an error message. I assume that error message occurs because there is no GPU in the base machine.

```
    RemoteBatchSubmit[env, 
 NetTrain[NetModel["LeNet"], "MNIST", TargetDevice -> "GPU"],
 RemoteProviderSettings -> <|"GPUCount" -> 1|>]
```

So, I then tried used the Wolfram directions/template `http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SetUpTheAWSBatchComputationProvider.html` to create a VM that has a GPU. I did so by insisting that the "Available Instance Type" be only of the "p3" kind. I think I succeeded in that I got the following back from AWS:

```
    RemoteBatchSubmissionEnvironment["AWSBatch", <|
    "JobQueue" -> 
    "arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:347566773302:job-queue/WolframJobQueue-\
    d3B4hun0Mh0A8IKa", 
    "JobDefinition" -> 
   "arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:347566773302:job-definition/\
    WolframJobDefinition-cf703d5831a3a0c:1", 
    "IOBucket" -> "gpuneeded-wolframjobdatabucket-1nr93xjmeu4g0"|>]
```

But then, when I try running this code:

```
RemoteBatchSubmit[env2, 
nt = NetTrain[NetModel["LeNet"], "MNIST", TargetDevice -> "GPU"], 
RemoteProviderSettings -> <|"GPUCount" -> 1|>]
```

it appears to hang forever (several hours at least) in "Runnable."  I've looked at a discussion of this issue on [Wolfram Community and posted there](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2142912), but so far no response. Maybe I will have better luck here on StackExchange? Also, I have a Free Trial Account on AWS and conceivably that is the issue??

Also, in my frustration I also tried using Azure. I kind of had the same experience there. I get everything to work until I try to "deploy" a NC4as T4 v3 VM, which is one of the cheaper ways of getting something with an NVIDA GPU. But Azure returns "Fail" on the deployment and gives me an absolutely incomprehensible error message. I don't really care if I use Azure or AWS to solve my problem, so if anyone has wisdom on getting GPU VMs to work on Azure, that would also be welcome.

Frustrated!